# Replace preprocessor macro by typedef of the same name

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to replace a macro with a proper typedef with the same name. I have

```
#define FooType char*
```

in a third party library and this breaks some of my code (more precisely: some code I am forced to use and which I can't change by myself). I want to replace it by a typedef of the same name and then `#undef` the macro. I tried something like that:

```
#define TMP_MACRO FooType
#undef FooType
typedef TMP_MACRO FooType;
#undef TMP_MACRO
```

But the preprocessor expands this to:

```
typedef FooType FooType;
```

(at least that is what `g++ -E` told me). So the macro `TMP_MACRO` is not expanded immediatelly. As 'FooType' is not there, it does not compile.

How can I replace the macro `FooType` by a proper type and undefine the macro afterwards? Or is this impossible?

Comment: Start by filing a bug report with the third party and have the sinner chastised.

Comment: Thought about this too - this is an impressive example why macros are evil :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `typedef` declaration is usually on one line, but line numbers mean nothing to the compiler.

```
typedef FooType
#undef FooType
FooType;
```

Comment: Awesome! That made me laught really hard! Thank you! :)

Comment: Yeah, I also tried a few different things and then was amused when I thought of this.

Comment: +1 Brilliant way to use the language and preprocessor's difference in treating newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply

```
#undef FooType
typedef char* FooType
```

The output you're getting is correct, since you instruct the preprocessor to replace `TMP_MACRO` with `FooType` (the fact that you `undef` FooType afterwards counts for nothing in regards to this).

Comment: Then I would have to maintain this line - every time, the third party library changes their macro "FooType" to something else, I'd have to change my line too. I want to extract the information from the third party library, not dublicate it.

Comment: @Sh4pe I doubt that's possible (might be wrong). Eagerly waiting for an answer...